# azure search SDK add parameter

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using azure search sdk and it works great - for my project. But I have a small issue, I'd like to send some search parameters, like API allows, using the SDK.

using the API I can set **fuzzy=true**
On search explorer, on azure portal, you can pass parameters like this:
**search terms, $fuzzy=true, $top=10**

Any way to do the same using the SDK? I need to set the **fuzzy** parameter to **true**.

**p.s. This question is for search and not for suggester!**

Answer (score 1):

For Fuzzy Search (as opposed to suggesters) you will likely want to leverage the Lucene Query Expressions with a ~ after the words you want to do fuzzy search over.  Here is an [example of a query](http://fiddle.jshell.net/liamca/gkvfLe6s/1/?index=nycjobs&apikey=252044BE3886FE4A8E3BAA4F595114BB&query=api-version=2015-02-28-Preview%26$select=business_title%26queryType=full%26search=business_title:asosiate~) that uses Lucene Query Expressions (queryType=full) in REST.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for search sdk. I need a way to pass the search options (parameters).

Answer (score 1):

For fuzzy search to work in the SDK you need to:

1. Make sure you're using at least version [4.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/4.0.1-preview/) of the Microsoft.Azure.Search NuGet package
2. Set the QueryType in your SearchParameters to Full
3. Append a tilda to the end of each word you are searching

So the following will do a fuzzy search on the word fish

```
var searchText= "fish~";
var searchParameters = new SearchParameters
{
  QueryType = QueryType.Full                
};

var searchResults = searchIndexClient.Documents.Search(searchText, searchParameters)
```